# How to save the audio file from IPython?

Tags: python, audio, ipython

How to save the audio file using `ipd.display`?

Just a minimal sample here

```py
from IPython.display import Audio 
from IPython.core.display import display
import librosa
audio_data, sample_rate = librosa.load('/Users/0_hey.wav', sr=None)
ipd.Audio(audio_data, rate=sample_rate)
```

Then it plays a sound, but I don't know how to save the audio file.

I know that we can download it by clicking the right bottom.
[image]
But I hope it can also be written in codes.

Answer (score 3):

The `display.Audio` is a widget, a user interface component that provides Audio controls. After the [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html):

> When this object is returned by an input cell or passed to the display function, it will result in Audio controls being displayed in the frontend (only works in the notebook).

`audio_data` is a numpy array and you can use any library that works with such data structures. `PySoundFile` is a solid choice, also recommended by `librosa`, library that you are using.

```
import soundfile as sf

# Write out audio as 24bit flac, change accordingly
sf.write('audio.flac', audio_data, sample_rate, format='flac', subtype='PCM_24')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So first, I have no idea why the playback sound is very low(Do you know why?). Second, librosa write function is removed in version0.8, so I think Librosa is not a good way for me

Comment: @Megan My answer does not use `librosa`, but the `PySoundFile`. The playback volume depends on the data. Scale it up to increase the volume.

Comment: Yes, i know you use pysoundfile. I mean you mentioned we can use librosa, but librosa is not compatible with the version over 0.8

Comment: What do you mean by "not compatible"? The answer has no relation to librosa. It's not using any deprecated (sub)modules.